# Need to parse a large json file

Tags: java, json

Currently i am getting into "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"
below is the code written, here i am passing the input-stream to get the
 JsonReader object to proceed further. Please let me know what should the
 best approach. Thanks in Advance.

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    JsonObject element = new JsonParser().parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();
```

//stacktrace

```
com.domo.connector.util.MagicException: Failed parsing JSON source: JsonReader at line 1 column 80720228 to Json
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.api.Client.get(Client.java:125)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.api.Client.get(Client.java:86)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.api.AdhocReportClient.getFirstPage(AdhocReportClient.java:24)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.ProcessRecords.getClientWithFirstPageOfData(ProcessRecords.java:116)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.ProcessRecords.readData(ProcessRecords.java:58)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.ProcessRecordsFunctionalTest.testCustomer(ProcessRecordsFunctionalTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Failed parsing JSON source: JsonReader at line 1 column 80720228 to Json
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:88)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.parser.AdapTVParser.parse(AdapTVParser.java:45)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.api.Client.get(Client.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:132)
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:139)
    at com.google.gson.JsonArray.<init>(JsonArray.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:656)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:667)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:659)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:667)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:642)
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:44)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:84)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.parser.AdapTVParser.parse(AdapTVParser.java:45)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.api.Client.get(Client.java:102)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.api.Client.get(Client.java:86)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.api.AdhocReportClient.getFirstPage(AdhocReportClient.java:24)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.ProcessRecords.getClientWithFirstPageOfData(ProcessRecords.java:116)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.ProcessRecords.readData(ProcessRecords.java:58)
    at com.domo.connector.adaptv.ProcessRecordsFunctionalTest.testCustomer(ProcessRecordsFunctionalTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
```

Comment: http://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/ hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: what is the size of your json file is it so big ?

Answer (score 0):

If your document is very big, you can not build a DOM tree / JSON object in memory. You have to use a pull or SAX parser and compute the document step by step. That will force you to rewrite the code that handles the JSON objects.

See [JSON simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

If you are parsing some kind of stream, the event-based approach would be better, if it is just a file, a pull parser will suffice.